# Can not build ffmpeg with gpu acceleration on macOS

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, nvidia, video-processing

I'm trying to use my GPU for video encoding/decoding operations on macOS.

- OS: MacOS 10.12.5 (Sierra) //hackintosh if it matters
- CUDA Toolkit 8.0 installed
- NVidia GTX 1080 with latest web driver

Followed this guides:

- https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/MacOSX
- https://developer.nvidia.com/ffmpeg

Config:

```
./configure --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-nvenc \
--enable-nonfree --enable-libnpp \
--extra-cflags=-I/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-8.0/include \
--extra-ldflags=-L/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-8.0/lib
```

Got this error:

```
ERROR: cuvid requested, but not all dependencies are satisfied: cuda
```

[config.log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxAsLYQ3Gtiyel8wUVp2cC05X0k) - full configure log

I did not install Video Codec SDK (not sure how to make it on macOS, just thought that it may come with cuda toolkit) and according to this [page](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro) I have a lot of limitations on OSX.

Is it possible on macOS? Or this will work only for linux/windows?

Comment: well at least you stated your using a hackintosh. 

might want to give brew a try, and see if that helps.